# Robolectric & Junit

Tags: android, junit, robolectric

**I am getting the following exception while trying to run tests with robolectric on eclipse. Stumped what is causing this issue. Anyone faced the same?**

My test class has only the following. I am just starting on it.

```
import static org.junit.Assert.assertTrue;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner;

@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner.class)
public class ABCMainActivityTest {

  @Test
  public void shouldFail() {
      assertTrue(true);
  }
}
```

Getting the following exception when i execute with the argument -noverify

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Test class can only have one constructor
    at org.junit.runners.model.TestClass.<init>(TestClass.java:37)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.<init>(ParentRunner.java:73)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.<init>(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:55)
    at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner$HelperTestRunner.<init>(RobolectricTestRunner.java:643)
    at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner.getHelperTestRunner(RobolectricTestRunner.java:261)
    at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner$2.evaluate(RobolectricTestRunner.java:194)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:263)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:68)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:47)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:231)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:60)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:222)
    at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner$1.evaluate(RobolectricTestRunner.java:175)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:300)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
```

else if i am not passing any arguments i am getting a

```
java.lang.VerifyError: Expecting a stackmap frame at branch target 46
```

Comment: Please show some of the code. All I can tell from this stack trace is that you may have an extra constructor somewhere in your test class.

Comment: Edited. including the class I wrote for test. The irony is I don't have any constructor in the class

Comment: I just tested this code in netbeans, it compiles fine and the test even passes.  Could it be something going on in your eclipse?  I'm using robolectric 2.2

Comment: Yeah. Seems to be an environment issue. Checking my eclipse workspace. Thanks for checking though.

Comment: @Yasir Have you resolved this?

Comment: Have tried with the new version of Robolectric?